# Excel: Assigning 1/0 to True/False

Tags: excel, pivot-table, spreadsheet

[image: table]

I have a table of True and Falses that I want to count in a pivot table. But I would like to count how many True values per employee by assigning a 1 to True and a 0 to False. How do I go about that?

[image]

Right now Excel is just counting whatever is in the columns as 1 when I insert a pivot table. I'd like to show how many True values there are.

Comment: Straightforward using measures in Power Pivot if that's an option for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to use a pivot table?

An easy option is to add another column to your data with this formula:

```
=countif(<range-of-column>,TRUE())
```

So for the first row, it might look something like this:

```
=countif(B2:B4,TRUE())
```

This is basically going through the row and counting the number of TRUEs that exist in that row.

Comment: Yes, I do need to use a pivot table. I was wondering how to make the pivot table code all the trues as 1 and falses as 0 to count it.

Comment: Maybe use helper columns and pivot on that?